# "How to fix 'Exception calling "LoadXml" with "1" argument(s): "Data at root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1."

Tags: powershell

I'm running the following code in powershell:

```
$xml = "443"
$sourceXml=New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$sourceXml.LoadXml($xml)
```

And I am receiving the error about "Data at the root level is invalid.  Line 1, position 1."

I've looked through other questions and answers and found that it may be related to the UTF formatting and a ghost character, but I am unsure of how to fix this issue in powershell as most of the solutions are for C# or other coding languages.

```
$xml = "443"
$sourceXml=New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$sourceXml.LoadXml($xml)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, was not storing the full properly formatted XML code in $xml.  Silly me, thanks anyways!